# Flutter wait for widget to load or wait for settings

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm struggling with some problem how to optimize app. May be you'll help me. So the thing is that within my app I have some async call that loads config. Basically what I do **now**:

1. Create `MaterialApp` with `home` property assigned to some `LoadingScreen`.
2. Wrap all of this with `FutureBuilder`.
3. When future which delivers user settings is done replace `home` property with actual screen content (which is settings dependent).

I think it could be not the best way to solve this problem. So I've tried build the entire `MaterialApp` with content after future is done. Then the problem appears - for a second there's black screen. Meaning `LoadingScreen` has already gone, but `MaterialApp` need a second or so to render.

Here for user settings I'm using `SharedPreferences`, where I store things like selected theme (light, dark, system) and language. Both of those should be applied to the `MaterialApp` and I don't want to load it with default settings and then reload with user settings. Also I'm afraid of some blinking if theme will be changed from light to dark right after app started.

What will you suggest? What is the proper way to solve the problem?

Comment: Use a splash screen to load the settings. This is a first thing user sees under your material app and after loading settings navigate to actual app which uses the settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Map globalSettings;

main() => runApp(Launcher());

class Launcher extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {'splash': (_) => Splash(), 'app': (_) => App()},
      initialRoute: 'splash',
      builder: (context, child) => SafeArea(child: child),
    );
  }
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSettings().then((_) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'app'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(color: Colors.blue);
}

Future<void> loadSettings() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  globalSettings = {'foo': 'bar'};
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(globalSettings != null);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('${globalSettings['foo']}')),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: instead of global settings you could use any state-management solution.